# Spring AOP and transaction add custom interceptors

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

My spring definition regarding trasnsaction are defined as following:

```
<bean id="txInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="defaultServiceOperation"
          expression="execution(* x.y.service.*Service.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="defaultServiceOperation"
          advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>                        
         <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Now, I'd like to add some additional interceptors that my App contains, that will run before every time that transaction interceptor is invoked. i.e. I'd like to add to the pointcut 'defaultServiceOperation' other advise, or add to the 'defaultTxAdvice' pre interceptors. Something like:

```
<property name="preInterceptors">
      <list>
           <ref bean="optimisticLockingInterceptor"/>
           <ref bean="deadLockingInterceptor"/>            
      </list>
</property>
```

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Is the question not clear or Spring doesn't support such pattern and there is no solution?

Answer (score 1):

How many may be the Interceptors you may provide, the TransactionInterceptor should be provided first in the List of Interceptors you mention.